# Typeform WordPress Integration

Tags: wordpress, api, webhooks, typeform

I have a form in Typeform, So if an user enter his details the details should be send via webhook api and it should be stored in my Wordpress website that's what I'm looking for . 1st doing API so I'm looking for some code or functions to get datas from the Form url of the typeform. Without Plugin so I want to learn through codes ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## API endpoint

First you need to build your own API endpoint to receive [Typeform Webhook](https://developer.typeform.com/webhooks/) payload. I assume you will be building this in PHP since you are using Wordpress.

You can create a `webhook.php` file in your Wordpress installation, eg. in `/wp-content` directory:

```php
<?php
$headers = getallheaders();
$header_signature = $headers["Typeform-Signature"];
$secret = "abc123";  // replace with a unique webhook secret

$payload = @file_get_contents("php://input");
$hashed_payload = hash_hmac("sha256", $payload, $secret, true);
$base64encoded = "sha256=".base64_encode($hashed_payload);

if ($header_signature !== $base64encoded) {
  die("invalid signature");
}

// now you can process webhook payload
// see https://developer.typeform.com/webhooks/example-payload/
$data = json_decode($payload);
$definition = $data->form_response->definition;  // form definition
$answers = $data->form_response->answers;        // respondent answers

// you could save it to your wordpress database
// code below depends on what questions you have in your typeform
require_once "../wp-load.php";
global $wpdb; // see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/
$wpdb->insert('my_typeform_data', array(
    'name'         => $answers[0]->text,
    'phone_number' => $answers[1]->phone_number
));
```

## Setup webhook

Now you can [setup webhook for your typeform](https://www.typeform.com/help/a/webhooks-360029573471/):

- click *Connect* in top menu
- click *Webhooks*
- click *Click Add a webhook* button
- enter URL to your webhook script, eg. `https://example.com/wp-content/webhook.php`
- click *Save webhook* button

To secure your webhook:

- click *Edit* button next to your webhook
- enter custom secret (see the `$secret` variable above)

For testing:

- click the *View deliveries* button next to your webhook
- click *Send test request* button